# Leaflet + prunecluster: get the list of the clusters that are shown in the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working on a leaflet map where many markers are shown with prunecluster, and I need to get the list of clusters that are currently shown in the map.

I have initialized the clusters with

```
var pruneCluster = new PruneClusterForLeaflet(150, 70);
```

The only array of the cluster I'm seeing in the developers tools and in the code is `pruneCluster.Cluster._clusters`. Actually it is a mostly exact representation of the clusters shown in the map, but, sometimes, the length of that array is different from the number of clusters that are shown in the map. I.e., that array doesn't represent the situation I have in the map.

What array should I use?

Answer (score 0):

That `pruneCluster.Cluster._clusters` contains all the clusters it calculated, but since you can pan and zoom the map, the visible clusters can be a subset of it.

You can iterate over the clusters and test if they are visible. Like this:

```
// Get the bounds of the map visible in the browser
// 'map' is your Leaflet map
var boundsOfView = map.getBounds();

// Iterate all prune clusters
var allClusters = pruneCluster.Cluster._clusters;
var clustersInView = [], clusterBounds;
for (var i = 0; i < allClusters.length; i += 1) {
    clusterBounds = allClusters[i].bounds;
    // Is this cluster visible? (within the visible bounds?)
    if (boundsOfView.intersects([[clusterBounds.minLat, clusterBounds.minLng], [clusterBounds.maxLat, clusterBounds.maxLng]])) {
        // Yes, visible, so store it
        clustersInView.push(allClusters[i]);
    }
}

// Now you have all your visible clusters in 'clustersInView'
```

It is using these Leaflet methods:

- [`getBounds()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-methods-for-getting-map-state) to get the bounds of the visible part of the map
- [`intersects()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#latlngbounds) to test if the boundaries of a cluster intersect the bounds of the map, i.e. visible or not

And of PruneCluster:

- [`bounds`](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster/blob/master/PruneCluster.ts) (line 83 in the source code), which contains the min/max coordinates of a cluster

Hope it helps!